# How to query for foreign key onupdate/ondelete?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-schema

I have the following query to return foreign key details:

```
SELECT
    tc.constraint_name,
    tc.table_name,
    kcu.column_name,
    ccu.table_schema AS foreign_table_schema,
    ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
    ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name,
    pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(pg_constraint.oid, true) AS foreign_definition
FROM
    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
      ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
      ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
    JOIN pg_constraint
      ON pg_constraint.conname = tc.constraint_name
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```

From this, I can get most of the information I need to re-consturct a foreign key. The only thing missing is the on update & on delete information (although this can be parsed out from the `foreign_definition`). I've been trying to figure a way to receive these details without parsing it out, but so far I have had no luck.

Does anyone have any details on which table I can find the on update and on delete details?

This is specifically for Postgres.

Comment: did you try `information_schema.referential_constraints`?.. there are two columns `update_rule` and `delete_rule`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?..

```
SELECT
    tc.constraint_name,
    tc.table_name,
    kcu.column_name,
    ccu.table_schema AS foreign_table_schema,
    ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name,
    ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name,
    pg_catalog.pg_get_constraintdef(pg_constraint.oid, true) AS foreign_definition,
    update_rule,
    delete_rule
FROM
    information_schema.table_constraints AS tc
    JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu
      ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
    JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu
      ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
    JOIN pg_constraint
      ON pg_constraint.conname = tc.constraint_name
    LEFT OUTER JOIN information_schema.referential_constraints rc on tc.constraint_name = rc.constraint_name and ccu.table_schema = rc.constraint_schema

WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY'
```